# Sum of digits: $S(k+l)<150, S(l+m)<150, S(m+k)<150$ and $S\left(\frac{k+l+m}3 \right)>2001$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers

Let $S(n)$ denotes the sum of all digits of the positive integers $n$.

Are there exist positive integer numbers $k,l,m$ such that

1. $\frac{k+l+m}3 \in \mathbb Z$
2. $S(k+l)<150, S(l+m)<150, S(m+k)<150$ and $S\left(\frac{k+l+m}3 \right)>2001$?

#### My work

I think these numbers are

$k= 444..45$ $444...5$ $555...5$

$l= 444..45$ $555...5$ $444...5$

$m= 555...5$ $444..45$  $444...5$

where $k$ consist $19+19+19$ digits

Then $S(k+m)=S(m+l)=S(l+k)=1+1+9+8\times17=147<150$ and $\frac{k+l+m}3 \in \mathbb Z$.

But I don't know how to calculate sum of all digits $\frac{k+l+m}3$

Comment: Please avoid math-only titles. See [Guidelines for good use of MathJax in question titles](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233) for more information.

Comment: @soupless: I have edited

Comment: You need $\frac {k+l+m}3$ to have at least $223$ digits to have a digit sum of $2001$.  Most of those need to be $9$s if it is that small.  The pairwise sums must have a lot of zero digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $k=10^{667}$ and $l=m=1$, one has
$$S(k+l)=S(l+m)=S(m+k)=2\lt 150$$
and
$$S\bigg(\frac{k+l+m}{3}\bigg)=S(\underbrace{33...3}_{666}4)=3\times 666+4=2002\gt 2001$$

---

Your example does not satisfy $S(\frac{k+l+m}{3})\gt 2001$ since
$$S\bigg(\frac{k+l+m}{3}\bigg)\lt S(\underbrace{99...9}_{19\times 3+1})= 9\times(19\times 3+1)=522$$